# expo node sendgrid : how can I send an email to reset password and attach user to link to retrieve back once user is on app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, expo, sendgrid, reset-password

i have a node / react native project. I want to reset a password and send an email to the user. I send a link to my client. When user clicks on that link he is being directed to the screen where he can choose a new password. I do need to get somehoe the users id or email or some identifier, so I can save the new password.

```
sendResetPasswordLink: async (email, link) => {
  const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  const link = "exp://192.168.2.30:19000/"
    const msg = {
      to: 'test@example.com',
      from: 'test@example.com', // Use the email address or domain you verified above
      subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
      text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
      html:  `<a href=${link}${email}>This is Link<a/>`,
    };
}
```

from my client:

```
...
   const link = Linking.createURL('/ChangePassword');
   axios.post('/send_reset_password_link', {email, link})
...
```

If I send a link with route to my backend, then I can only render the form to reset password from my backend. Is there any way I can just have a form on my client, direct the user back to it once he clicks the link but also pass/grab then the user(id or email)?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an OTP system made.
The user then enters his email, he is redirected to another screen where he can enter a code, during this time, you send an OTP to his email. Once the code is verified, you can proceed to the change password screen.